# Is session_set_cookie_params secure?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

We are currently using a custom login system that sets a hash in the database on one site, and then when the user transfers between domain and sub-domains it logs them in. It doesn't always log the user in so they click on on the login link/button and it takes them to the login and if they have a session it loads it otherwise it shows the login page.

We would like to get away from that and use something better. With php there is `session_set_cookie_params` and we were wondering is this secure?

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600, "/", ".example.com");
```

If this isn't a good way to use a session across multiple domains what is a better one?

We also have a few subdomains that use their own login system where the same user has a different username/password on that system, will this/that be a problem? We feel that it could be possible that two different people could have the same session id logging two different people on to the same account, since they manage their own sessions.

Comment: secure for/from what? Security isn't a checklist on a marketing sheet. you can't just magically make something "secure" by sprinkling in a bit of code like you would with salt on food..

Comment: I think mainly be user **A** logging in as user **B** also I was reading a blog that said **Don’t Share With Sub Domains** but they never said why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a fine approach, however you have to consider that, if all domains/subdomains you want involved in the same session are not on same server or reside within different applications, that you need to provide some common backend session-storage mechanism that all applications can access for session data.

As far as dealing with multiple logins, you would likely need a logical way to link the logins together so that you can understand that a valid session under one login could be transferred to another login on a different domain.  This is really your largest security concern, and one that should likely be addressed by implementing a single sign-in mechanism.

Comment: We are using memcache for session storage, so they should be linked. How could/would you suggest logging into service **B** from service **A** where my id = 1 on **A** and your id = 1 on **B**? I would now be pulling data from the database as id 1 which would be you...

Comment: @TheBoogieMan Now that IS that problem isn't it.  Until you have a way to map ID's in each application to some unique, user-specific ID, you have no way to handle that user crossing application boundaries. Hopefully, you have some common way to link the accounts across applications (i.e. email address, username, etc.).

Comment: 3 of our services would work fine without the mapping because they share the same user base the rest have their own user base (due to the fact of poor design by CTO). But yes, they do all contain the user's email address, which could be used to link the non-related apps together!